# How to add spring-security-oauth2-client:5.3.2.RELEASE to spring boot 2.1.2.RELEASE?

Tags: spring-boot

can anyone tell how to add spring-security-oauth2-client:5.3.2.RELEASE dependency to existing spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE ? I am using spring boot configuration processor 2.1.3.RELEASE . I tried to manually add the spring security maven dependency but it resolves to spring-security-oauth2-client:5.1.3.RELEASE only. We need to a minimum of 5.2 version as we need the OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager class in our solution which is available from thsi version. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dependency management to directly specify the versions of artifacts to be used when they are encountered in transitive dependencies.
If you are using maven you can do the following

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- spring-security-oauth2-client:5.3.2.RELEASE dependency -->
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

This will now only override the oauth2-client version you are getting from spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE dependency.

You can do similary in gradle also using dependency management plugin

```
plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version <<version>>
}
dependencyManagement {
    dependencies {
        //mention your spring-security-oauth2-client:5.3.2.RELEASE dependency
    }
}
```

[dependency management - gradle](https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current/reference/html/),
[dependency management - maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)